# Detachable tubing connections (joints) for frame assembly

Tags: design, fasteners, connections

I am looking into fabricating a steel tubing frame that needs to be dis/assembled (applies to many larger furniture like bed, shelving unit, wardrobe, cupboard, cabinet, ...).

What are the variants of the steel equivalent of a butt-joint and their pros/cons?

I have only found information on joints for construction steel (think skyscraper-sized double-T section) so far.

I have not found anything for closed sections in DIY sizes like 20/30/40 mm or 1 inch (easily available in hardware stores).

I am certain there must be something in literature. I might not be searching with the right terms.

Ideally, the connectors would be "invisible", i.e. hidden inside the tubing (square or rectangular).

I am considering welding a bolt to one part and a cap onto the other - one hole for the bolt, and another to enable tightening a nut inside the tubing:

[image]

Drawbacks: only one fastener, bolts may be too small, assembly of the nut very "fiddly".
Pros: does not weaken tubing (depending on load/bending moment).

Another option:

[image]

Drawbacks: profile not tensioned, "snug" fit depends on availability and tolerances of tubing.

I'm also interested in connector-hardware made for this purpose.

Comment: Your first image could suit a 'cam lock' setup?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift As in woodworking? I've considered it, but it may need a tubular section to sit in (difficult to weld in), and I have doubts the tensioning works in steel (zinc cast parts?).

Comment: Pins with taper locks - check those used on tailgates and some scaffolding systems.

Comment: You can also get fun magnetic nut spinners to help with the fiddly aspect :)

Comment: What about dovetail with a pin?

Comment: Could you post examples? I was not able to find much on the suggested methods. The same question at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/155241/rectangular-steel-tube-bolted-connection. Lots of examples and solutions (products) at https://www.mcmaster.com/Metal-Structural-Framing-Tubing/ Also https://www.mcmaster.com/weld-nuts and https://weldtalk.hobartwelders.com/forum/weld-talk-topic-archive/welding-projects/15877-how-to-make-tubing-accept-a-bolt

Answer (score 0):

See as an example the frequently used principle in the furniture industry.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but see the comments to the question: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38417/detachable-tubing-connections-joints-for-frame-assembly/40104#comment68956_38417